# How to use input type hidden in Angular FormBuilder?

Tags: angular-reactive-forms

I am running an application using Angular CLI 9.0.7. In this application I use FormBuilder to with two input fields of type hidden. When I run the application I get the message:

**Error: Cannot find control with name: 'codigoIbgeMunicipioForm'**

[image]

How can I do to use input hidden in my form?

This is my component source code where I defined the input hidden fields.

```
  private adicionarEnderecoFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      cepForm: ['', [Validators.required, CepValidator.cepValido]],
      numeroEnderecoForm: ['', Validators.required],
      complementoForm: [''],
      tipoLogradouroForm: ['', Validators.required],
      logradouroForm: ['', Validators.required],
      bairroForm: ['', Validators.required],
      cidadeForm: ['', Validators.required],
      estadoEnderecoForm: ['', Validators.required],
      codigoIbgeMunicipioForm: [''], // <- look the field id defined here
      paisForm: ['BR'], // <- this field is hidden type too
    }, { validators: LojistaEnderecoValidator.enderecoDuplicado(this.enderecos) });
  }
```

And this my Html file

```
            <div FormGroupName="enderecoFormGroup">
                <input formControlName="codigoIbgeMunicipioForm" id="codigoIbgeMunicipioForm" type="hidden" />
                <input formControlName="paisForm" id="paisForm" type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find what was wrong, so I removed the component from the project, created the component again, pasted the code back, compiled and it worked ...

Strange, but it worked.